# How to Include Table Element Without Changing Grouping

Tags: visual-foxpro

How do I add a table element without changing grouping?  This select works as intended:

```
SELECT cid, cnumber, cenrtyp, MAX(nqpoints);
from demographicenroll3.dbf;
WHERE cenrtyp = "RT" ;
GROUP BY cid, cnumber, cenrtyp ;
```

This gives me a list which includes only one of the records in the group cid, subgroup cnumber, that has the max nqpoints value, which is what I want.

But I need to include the unique record number of cnumber in my recordset, which is ecid - so I add ecid:

```
SELECT cid, cnumber, cenrtyp, MAX(nqpoints), ecid;
from demographicenroll3.dbf;
WHERE cenrtyp = "RT" ;
GROUP BY cid, cnumber, cenrtyp, ecid ;
```

But this doesn't work because it changes the grouping making the Max(nqpoints) incorrect.  Any tricks to get what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in a single query, but you can by making your existing query into a derived table in another query:

```
SELECT dmax.cid, dmax.cnumber, dmax.cenrtyp, maxpts, ecid ;
FROM demographicenroll3 d3
  JOIN (
     SELECT cid, cnumber, cenrtyp, MAX(nqpoints) AS maxpts;
     from demographicenroll3;
     WHERE cenrtyp = "RT" ;
     GROUP BY cid, cnumber, cenrtyp) dmax ;
    ON d3.cid = dmax.cid ;
    AND d3.cnumber = dmax.cnumber ;
    AND d3.cenrtyp = dmax.cenrtype ;
    AND d3.nqpoints = dmax.maxpts
```

Comment: I tried this but VFP gives error alias DMAX not found.  I know VFP supports self joins so I'm not sure what the reason for the error is.  Any troubleshooting suggestions?

Comment: Ok, finally woke up and actually looked for the problem (lol).  The query works now I'm just going through and checking results.  I'll be back...

Comment: This appears to give the correct resutls!  Thanks, my project is once again moving forward.